# Dealing with keystore files

Tags: mining, balances, reward

I have linux based miner with geth wallet. 
I've backed up keyfile (starting with UTC ... ..... ) into my second computer based on Windows where I've sucessfully imported it into Geth keystore folder.

I've runned up console with command

```
“eth.getBalance(eth.coinbase)”
```

and it shows up 0.

The thing is that my account has already some Ether as I'm checking it on Etherscan.

Can you please explain me what's happening ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think `eth.coinbase` does not exist.
You have to write `eth.accounts[i]` instead where `i` is the number of your account (you can see all your accounts with `eth.accounts`)

Comment: That sounds correct to me.  eth.coinbase is a default or author account so unless you set your account to be the coinbase, you have to use @DIstic 's command instead of the one you're using.